# Getting 2 values of cell in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two datagridviews. `datagridview1` and `datagridview2`. When I add a product from `datagridview1` to `datagridview2` the quantity of the product in `datagridview1` is transferred to `datagridview2`. Now when I remove a product from `datagridview2` I need it to transfer the quantity back to `datagridview1`.

[image]

Here is my code.:

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int ind = findIndexForItem(dgvPOScart.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

        int dgvCARTquantity = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPOScart.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
        int dgvPOSquantity = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPOScart.Rows[ind].Cells[5].Value.ToString());     
        int dgvnewADDquantity;

        dgvnewADDquantity = dgvPOSquantity + dgvCARTquantity;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dgvPOScart.SelectedRows)
        {    
            dgvPOScart.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);         
        }

    }
```

And the code for the helper:

```
        private int findIndexForItem(string name)
    {
        int ind = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvPOSproduct.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dgvPOSproduct.Rows[i].Equals(name))
            {
                ind = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ind;                
    }
```

How can I properly call `ind? Rows[ind]` is wrong because ind is the product ID or value or `cell[0]` and not row index. Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: In findIndexForItem, the test should be:  if (name==(string)dgvPOSproduct.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) ...

Comment: to be safe: _.Cells[whatever]_

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little weird, you are foreach-ing the SelectedRows but you're only calculating the new quantity for the current row, why?

Also, you shouldn't look at the products by their name since you have their ID (which is more unique than a name).

In order for this to work, you'll need something like this:

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var row in dgvPOScart.SelectedRows)
    {
        // Get the row in dgvProducts and the quantity he'll gain back
        var productRow = dgvPOSproduct.Rows[FindRowIndexByID(row.Cells[0].Value)];
        int qtyToAdd = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Value);

        // Add the quantity back
        productRow.Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToInt32(productRow.Cells[5].Value) + qtyToAdd;
    }
}

private int FindRowIndexByID(string id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgvPOSproduct.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dgvPOSproduct.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == id)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;               
}
```

Comment: It has some error sir. on btnremoveclick it says "object does not contain a definition on 'Cells' " for line 5 and 6. and on findrowindexbyid it says "cast the left hand side to type string" i guess i should just put toString() on that? but what about on buttonremove

Comment: Yes you should put .ToString() on the .Value in FindRowIndexByID. For the other error thats weird